# How to force text in an Android Dialog box to be flush left

Tags: android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

```
 var dialogView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view, null);
        Android.App.AlertDialog alertDialog;

        listview = dialogView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);

        var items = new string[] { "English", "español", "中文(s)", "中文(t)", "日本語", "हिन्दी", 
        "français", "Deutsche", "русский", "عربى" };
        //  var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, 
        items);
        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, items);
```

Without the Arabic when the list is displayed all the items are flush left.
However, since Arabic is a right-to-left language, the final entry (which is Arabic in Arabic) is displayed on the right. I would like it on this left so it aligns with the others.

How would I do that? GRAVITY?

Answer (score 0):

You could `android:gravity` property to define left alignment of content

like `list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:textColor="#f00"
   android:gravity="left"
   > 

</TextView>
```

**Or** use the `LTR` layout from Android 4.2 (sdk 17)

define `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```

then define the `android:textDirection="ltr"` in your `list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:textDirection="ltr"
   android:textColor="#f00"
   >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just forgot to add

```
android:gravity="left".
```